# Notification sound from URI parse does not work

Tags: android, uri, android-notifications

There are at least 7 questions on Stackoverflow related to this, I have tried every single suggestion and solution multiple times and none of them have worked. Here is my latest attempt:

```
private Notification createNotification() {
       Notification notification = new Notification();


       if(notifyImage=="food")
         {
           notification.icon = R.drawable.food;
           notification.sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://com.example.memoryGuide/raw/start");
         }
       else
       {
           notification.icon = R.drawable.bar; 
           notification.sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://com.example.memoryGuide/raw/start");
       }


       notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
       notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
       notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
       notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
       notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; 
       notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
       notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
       notification.ledOffMS = 1500;
       return notification;
 }
```

You can see the two times I try and use a sound which never works, but the icons work perfectly. I do not know if I am missing anything in order to get this to work, but all of the code I am using is in my post.

My sound file is in res/raw/start.mp3, I can get this sound to work when pressing a button, so the sound is fine.

I think the package name is right, my application at has this at the top of each class:

```
package com.example.memoryGuide;
```

Any ideas why the sound never plays?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
        + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/start");
```

Note one thing.

> [String android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getPackageName%28%29)

returns the package name of your android aplication. And

> package com.example.memoryGuide;

shows the package name of your source package name.

Comment: Thank you, it works now, well done on showing me how to get the package name! :)

Answer (score 4):

If this one work for you. Please vote up..........

Just put your sound file in Res\raw\siren.mp3 folder ::

Then put this code..This will definitely work for you.

For Custom Sound ::

```
 notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.siren);
```

For Default Sound ::

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

For Custom Vibrate ::

```
  long[] vibrate = { 0, 100, 200, 300 };
     notification.vibrate = vibrate;
```

For Default Vibrate ::

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

Comment: please don't post the exact same answer to several questions - they either don't really fit or the questions are duplicates (and should be flagged as such)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem while testing on `API 23`. While I do not know the cause of the problem, I *did* manage to find a workaround that got the job done.

---

In one of [Google's examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/Geofencing/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/geofencing/GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java), a notification is constructed thusly:

```
// Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

// Define the notification settings.
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        // In a real app, you may want to use a library like Volley
        // to decode the Bitmap.
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher))
        .setColor(Color.RED)
        .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
        .setContentText(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
        .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

// Dismiss notification once the user touches it.
builder.setAutoCancel(true);

// Get an instance of the Notification manager
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// Issue the notification
mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Notice the class [**`NotificationCompat.Builder`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html). For some reason which is beyond me, this did not play any sound **other than the default one**. In other words, only this worked:

```
// Define sound URI
Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION); // Default
...
builder.setSound(soundUri); //Set the sound to play
```

But this didn't:

```
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + 
                           getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.name_of_sound);
```

After simply replacing the builder class with [**`Notification.Builder`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) (available for `API >= 11`) the "*this didn't*" section above started working as expected.

**Conclusion**: use this if you're willing to sacrifice (or are not interested in) compatibility with `API < 11`.