# How to play notification sound from local file

Tags: android, notifications

```
    sound = Uri.parse("file://" + audioFilePath.getAbsolutePath());
    /*sound = Uri.fromFile(audioFilePath);*/
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            mBuilder
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(description)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setSound(sound);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
            }
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

The sound file is present in local storage. Notification working properly but sound doesn't play. I tried both way to parse Uri from file path.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your sound in your resource folder (which you should do anyway for notification sounds) and use Notification.Builder instead of NotificationCompat.Builder, you should be able to access it like this:

```
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + 
                       getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.name_of_sound);
Notification.Builder mBuilder =
                new Notification.Builder(this);
        mBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(description)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(sound);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        }
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36378881/6291515)

Comment: Is there a way to access a saved local file? Instead of actually adding it to the Resources? My app saves the file locally and I want it to play.